# Rate Limiting Cancellation token restore

Tags: algorithm, go

I am trying to understand rate limiting and having a hard time understanding this logic
https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/time/+/master:rate/rate.go;l=168;bpv=0;bpt=0

```
    // calculate tokens to restore
    // The duration between lim.lastEvent and r.timeToAct tells us how many tokens were reserved
    // after r was obtained. These tokens should not be restored.
    restoreTokens := float64(r.tokens) - r.limit.tokensFromDuration(r.lim.lastEvent.Sub(r.timeToAct))
```

If lim.LastEvent is from another reservation which is made in future compared to the current reservation we are cancelling, why do we need to take that duration into account (lim.LastEvent - r.timeToAct) ?
Why couldn't we simply have `restoreTokens = float64(r.tokens)` here ?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me.  You should write a test case that demonstrates incorrect behaviour and file an issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is actually a bug

I would like to recommend [watchdog](https://github.com/1996Paul-Wen/watchdog), a rate limiter that is more concise + more correct and effective than `time/rate`

`watchdog` is implemented using **ZERO POINT movement mechanism**.

it has **2** advantages:

- **Simpler implementation**. Thanks to ZERO POINT movement mechanism, the Structs and Token Calculation Methods provided by `watchdog` are both simpler than `golang.org/x/time/rate`, the official implementation.
- **More reliable limiting mechanism**. `watchdog` calculates the token correctly, providing reliability. The logic of `golang.org/x/time/rate` is wrong because it considers `reserved tokens` when returning tokens back to the limiter. This bug has been easily fixed by `watchdog`'s ZERO POINT movement mechanism.

At the usage level, `watchdog` completely covers the functions of `golang.org/x/time/rate` and maintains a similar interface, so it does not require too much mental burden to use.

For specific introduction and implementation, please refer to https://github.com/1996Paul-Wen/watchdog#readme